# GZIP + whitespace removal regex, or just GZIP

Tags: php, gzip, whitespace, minify

Should I remove spacing characters from stuff like HTML / CSS / JS before serving them GZipped?

Would that decrease their size even more?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807119/gzip-versus-minify for a great discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimizing before compression will indeed decrease the size.

Answer (score 1):

It will lower the size, but not by much.