# is loading jQuery library inline an effective way to decrease rendering time?

Tags: http, http-headers, shared-libraries

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807119/gzip-versus-minify) discussion around gzip, minified, and combining both for maximum compression effects made me wonder if I can get a net performance effect by placing jQuery libraries directly inside my HTML file?

I already do this for icon sprites, which I base64 encode and then load via CSS datasource, in an effort to minimize the number of HTTP requests.

Now I ask: do you know if loading the jQuery library in its raw min+gzip form, as available on the official production download link, would be more efficient compared to loading it via the Google AJAX libraries that are hosted on their CDN?

Comment: If you use the Google CDN, there's a very good chance the browser already has it cached, so loading it takes almost no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

You should always keep common items (like a JS library) in external files, because that allows for caching on your server, in the browser, and at many nodes along the way. Caching times dramatically outweigh compression or request times when looking at the overall speed of a page.

#### Longer Version:

There are a number of things to consider for this question. Here are the ones that came off the top of my head.

1. Minifying scripts and styles is always good for speed. I don't think there's much to discuss here.
2. Compression (and extraction in the browser) has an overhead. Firing up the gzip module takes time away from sending the request, so for small files or binary files (images, etc.), it's usually better to skip the gzip. Something large and consisting mostly of ascii (like a JS library), however, is a good thing to compress, so that checks out.
3. Reducing HTTP requests is generally a good thing to do. Note, though, that ever since HTTP 1.1 (supported in all major browsers), a new HTTP request does not mean a new socket connection. With `keep-alive`, the same socket connection can serve the webpage and all the affiliated files in one go. The only extra overhead on a request is the request and response headers which can be negligible unless you have a lot of small images/scripts. Just make sure these files are served from a [cookie-free domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/78227/what-is-a-cookie-free-domain).
4. Related to point 3, embedding content in the page does have the benefit of reducing HTTP requests, but it also has the drawback of adding to the size of the page itself. For something large like a JS library, the size of library vastly outweighs the size of the HTTP overhead needed for an extra file.
5. Now here's the kicker: if the library is embedded in the page, it will almost never be cached. For starters, most (all?) major browsers will NOT cache the main HTML page by default. You can add a `CACHE-CONTROL` meta tag to the page header if you want, but sometimes that's not an option. Furthermore, even if that page is cached, the rest of your pages (that are probably also using the library) will now need to be cached as well. Suddenly you have your whole site cached on the user's machine including many copies of the JS library, and that's probably not what you want to do to your users. On the other hand, if you have the JS library as an external file, it can be cached by itself just once, especially (as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) says) if the library is loaded from a common CDN like Google.
6. Finally, caching doesn't only happen in the client's browser. If you're running an enterprise-level service, you may have multiple server pools with shared and individual caches, CDN caches that have blinding speed, proxy caches on the way to your domain, and even LAN caches on some routers and other devices. So now I direct you back to the TL;DR at the top, to say that the speed-up you can gain by caching (especially in the browser) trumps any other consideration you are likely to encounter.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed and knowledgeable write up. I have some remarks based on what you say: not every "web page" is in fact a "page" in its classical sense. Consider a web app that is contained in a single HTML file and contains everything except the dynamic data that is pulled in by user interaction via XHR. If this was delivered to a mobile device with cache-control meta tags, I would hope the browser will respect that. If it doesn't, why would it respect the caching of an external include?

Comment: Good point. In the case of a mobile app (or other single-page-with-XHR-content application), you're right that caching the JS separately doesn't save any time. However, if you have a bunch externals, I would still keep them separate so you can make changes to the HTML page clear that from the cache, without clearing the JS too.