# Should I compress my JavaScript files if server support HTTP compression?

Tags: javascript, compression, http-compression

My server supports HTTP compression.
Is there any advantage to compressing my JavaScript files? (not minifying them)

Update and clarification to what I mean:

- [IIS HTTP Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) - the server takes care of compression
- [GZip compression - see response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807161/78256) - I pre-compress the archive and serve it as script.js.gz.

Comment: Well, it surely **compresses** the file contents, reducing its transferred size, and should speed up loading it

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807119/gzip-versus-minify

Comment: Guys, thanks for the quick responses. But do note that I'm asking about whether JS compression is good or redundant if I use HTTP compression, minifying aside.

Comment: What is JS compression?

Comment: GZipping the JavaScript file, like in the question David linked to.

Comment: Well then what's HTTP compression?

Comment: See update on what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing your JS file will lead to, as Ian answered, smaller size and thus faster downloads. This is really a must-have for people coming from mobile devices or low-internet speeds(say at a free wifi spot, for instance).

Comment: There's always a tradeoff, between processing and transferring. Using `gzip`, the client has to unzip the contents and put it back together, taking some extra processing...so it's not the best idea to use if the client is lower on resources. But obviously, a slow network (in whatever way), compression is great so that there's less to transfer