# Should I minify and concatenate javascript and CSS when using HTTP2/SPDY?

Tags: javascript, css, http, minify, spdy

Given the advantages of connection reuse and multiplexing in HTTP2 (and SPDY) and the availability of gzip compression, is the effort of adding a minification and concatenation step into a build process justified?

Comment: With HTTP2 (and SPDY) one of the main benefits is you do not need to worry about concatenating or bundling your JavaScript (or images into spritesheets) exactly because of multiplexing and connection reuse. In fact with HTTP2 it is advantageous to leave each resource in its own file so that each is independently cached by the browser, that way when you update, say, jquery.js, only that file will need to be sent to clients versus a larger bundled js file. As far as minification, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807119/gzip-versus-minify

Answer (score 5):

According to Surma from the Chrome team, on H2 you can and in fact should stop bundling because it's useless and to allow more efficient browser caching:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w--PU4HO9SM (time 1:10)

I think that minifying or obfuscating can still be desirable, depending on your needs.

Comment: An interesting related blog post to read is https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-http2/

Answer (score 1):

**Testing is the only true means of deciding to minify and/or concatenate when resources are being served via H2/SPDY.**

The idea behind HTTP/2 (H2) is to serve **small** static resources on the stream (*a single multiplexing TCP connection*). Tests have shown that "most" sites benefit an increase of speed by not concatenating resources (and even not using a CDN). It all depends on the sizes of the resources being served on H2/SPDY. I have seen one site increase speed by 30%+ and others w/o change.

With that inmind, my suggestion is too test by minifing all resources and not concatenating them.  I'd also test serving all common resources (not using a CDN - and that as well depends where your clients are).

**Resources:**

1. [Akamai](https://http2.akamai.com/)
2. [Columnist Patrick Stox](http://searchengineland.com/everyone-moving-http2-236716)
3. [HTTP/2 101 (Chrome Dev Summit 2015)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5oT_2ndjms)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you still need to minify and concatenate js and css files for the following reasons:

- script minifying and SPDY compression are not the same. a good minifier knows to take advantage of local scope and replace verbose variable names with short repetitive names that are compression-friendly.
- SPDY combines your requests so you don't have to stitch the scripts together. but not all browsers support SPDY
- SPDY 2 and 3 are binary incompatible. When a browser supports 2 and the server advertises 3, the connection falls back to HTTP 1.1 over SSL; there's no SPDY benefits at all
- loading 10 files through one request still incurs 10 fetches on the server side. combining the files reduces disk I/O.

Your question is comparable to "can I care less about writing efficient code now that the machine can run faster?"

The answer is NO. Don't be lazy. Code properly.

Comment: I think your assertion that it is "lazy" to not minify/concatenate files is unhelpful as it is without context. Were I started from scratch I think that's a fair call, but I work on a medium-large legacy codebase with time pressures from business stakeholders so (a) it is not trivial to implement these things and (b) there is no time/money to do these things. I've love to do many things, but if SPDY gets me most of the way there there are bigger fish to fry.

Comment: Given your context of not starting from scratch it makes sense to use whatever that's convenient to improve the product, even if it's marginal. I feel your pain. Keep your head up buddy.

Comment: minify+gzip will provide the greatest compression; however, weight the benefit of minification against the cost of a javascript build system. Minified may be faster to download but hard to debug if you don't use source maps. And setting up and maintaining a front end build system of course incurs a certain amount of labor.