# GZIP compression to Tomcat 7 but still my page size is same

Tags: struts2, gzip, http-compression

I have a lot of images on my webpage  comming from a file system configured in server.xml of Tomcat 7 .

Now I am trying to use gzip in Tomcat 7  but still there is no reduction in page size specially my images are of same size . I am using struts2 and  for compression  I have used following code in my server.xml file

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" maxPostSize="67589953" port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" compression="force" compressionMinSize="2048" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" compressableMimeType="image/jpeg"  />
```

[image]

Comment: <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" maxPostSize="67589953" port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" compression="force" compressionMinSize="2048" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" compressableMimeType="image/jpeg"  />

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/q/25773248/573032?

Comment: Thanks roman for your help , I just want to confirm the way I am using is correct or some improvement can be done here .

Comment: OT: is your  web page size 22M ?! If images are static, you can compress the file instead of configuring tomcat to do it for every image in every request.